# Close access to folder1, but open access to folder1/folder2

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, users

I'm setting up local hosting, and I need to configure user system as on popular hosting providers.

For example: I create user 'user1' in group, for example, 'users'. And I gave him home folder `/user/user1`.

In some hosting providers, when we connect to our account via SSH of SFTP, we find ourselves in our home directory (in my case it's `/user/user1`). But, we can't access to `/user` folder. We can't access to `/home`, `/var` and other directories, but we can access to `/bin` and other service directories.

`Chroot` is bad thing there, because if we use chroot, we need to copy all bin and some system files in our user folder (because user will use shell).

**I only need to close access by user group to parent directory (`/user`), some my folders (`/etc`, `/home`) and other `/user/` folders, but give access to home directory (for user1 it is `/user/user1`).**

How can I do this?

I tried:

```
sudo chmod 000 /user
sudo chmod 777 /user/user1
```

But when I tried to `cd /user/user1` I got "permission denied" error.

How to fix this mistake and configure this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to traverse a directory, the directory needs +x (execute permission). To be able to list the content of a directory, the directory needs +r (read permission).

```
[/tmp]$ mkdir -p foo/bar
[/tmp]$ chmod 111 foo
[/tmp]$ cd foo
[/tmp/foo]$ ls
ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied
[/tmp/foo]$ cd bar
[/tmp/foo/bar]$
```

1 is octal permission for execute (+x), but no other permission, for owner, group and other. On /users you probably want 711, as root is owner (and has full control), but execute only for others. Thus, I'm able to change into a subdirectory, but unable to list the content of the directory.

As others have execute, anyone will be able to change into a subdirectory, provided they know the name of it.

You may also want to look into for instance SELinux or Apparmour, which can limit permissions in a more granular and flexible way than simple file permissions.

In short:

- The execute bit allows users to enter a directory, and access files and directories inside it.
- The read bit allows users to list the content of a directory.
- The write bit allows users to create files and directories inside it.
- The sticky bit only allows owner (or root) to modify a file or directory inside it.

[This article](https://www.hackinglinuxexposed.com/articles/20030424.html) provides some informations on how file system permissions work on Linux (and other Unices).

Comment: Thanks, it works! I have one question more: can I close access to folder only for user group without changing owner to this group?

Comment: No, traditional Unix permissions only allows permissions for owner, group and others. However, you can use [ACLs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists) for this. Access Control List are a lot more flexible and fine grained - and a lot harder to maintain.